# repeater is not updated after adding item to array

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I made a repeater in angular that shows some data from a json array.

```
 <html ng-app="myApp">
<head>
    <title>Suitcases</title>
</head>
    <body ng-controller="suitCaseController">
        <h2>SuitCases</h2>

        <ul class="nav">
            <li><a href="#addSuitcase"> Add New SuitCase </a></li>
        </ul>


        <div ng-repeat="suitcase in suitcases">
            <input type="checkbox" ng-model="suitcase.Locked" />    
            <p ng-bind="suitcase.Locked"></p>
            <p ng-bind="suitcase.Wheels"></p>   
        </div>

        <div ng-view></div>

        <script type="text/javascript" src="/Scripts/angular.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="/Scripts/angular-route.js"></script>
        <script>

            var myApp = angular.module('myApp', ['ngRoute']);

            myApp.config([
                '$routeProvider',
                function($routeProvider) {
                    $routeProvider.
                        when('/addSuitcase', {
                            templateUrl: 'suitcase/addsuitcase',
                            controller: 'suitCaseController'
                        }).
                        otherwise({
                            redirectTo: '/'
                        });
                }
            ]);

            angular.module('myApp').controller('suitCaseController', function ($scope, suitcaseRepository) {

                suitcaseRepository.GetSuitcases().success(function (data) {
                    $scope.suitcases = data;
                });

                $scope.AddSuitcase = function(suitcase) {
                    console.log(suitcase);
                    $scope.suitcases.push(suitcaseRepository.AddSuitcase(suitcase));
                    console.log($scope.suitcases);
                }

            });

            angular.module('myApp').factory('suitcaseRepository', function ($http) {

                return {
                    AddSuitcase: function(suitcase) {
                        return suitcase;
                    },
                    GetSuitcases: function() {
                        var url = '/SuitCase/GetSuitcases';
                        return $http.post(url);
                    }
                };
            });

        </script>
    </body>
</html>
```

The form for new items is loaded through the route provider and looks like this:

```
<form>
Locked: <input type="checkbox" ng-model="suitcase.Locked" />
Wheels: <input type="text" ng-model="suitcase.Wheels" />
<button ng-click="AddSuitcase(suitcase)">Add</button>
```

If I use this form to add an item to the array, the repeater is not updating. If I paste the form in the main code then it actually adds items to the list that is shown.

What am I missing here? Why is the repeater not updated if I use a seperately loaded view?

Comment: I guess you're getting issues when you're declaring multiple `modules` on same app, which has no significant at all.

Comment: is `console.log($scope.suitcases);` in `$scope.AddSuitcase` showing the updated list??

Comment: @Vineet there is only one module declaration... the others are references and perfectly valid

Comment: Just give a try with `myApp.controller` and `myApp,factory` :)

Comment: @Vineet that is pointless since `angular.module('moduleName').compnentName..` is a standard practice for referencing existing modules and is actually recommended in some style guides over using variables

Comment: @charlietfl, thanks a lot. By clearing this out for me :-)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The main problem is you have 2 instances of `suitCaseController`.

One is in the main html and the other is in the `<ng-view>`.

Each time you initialize a controller it is a *new instance* so the one that is being used to repeat the `suitcases` is not connected to the instance in the form

To show this in tree structure it would look something like:

```
<body ng-controller="suitCaseController">
     <!-- some html doing ng-repeat using first instance of controller-->
     <ng-view>
         <!-- nested instance of controller -->
         <form  ng-controller="suitCaseController">
      </ng-view>

<body>
```

If you shared the actual data object of `suitcases` through your service then the data would be the same in both instances... but having nested instances of the same controller is not ideal and is confusing

Comment: Does this mean that a view automatically is/should be connected to a seperate controller? Can I use multiple views in one controller?

Comment: I've never even tried `ng-view` without declaring a controller. You might try that and see what happens. It's not the norm though. If the data object itself is shared across controllers though you have reference to same object in both places..thus changes to one reference will reflect in view of the other

Comment: I found out that the routeprovider is creating a new instance of the controller. So I removed the line controller: 'suitCaseController' and now it is working as expected: 1 instance of suitCaseController and updating the repeater when I add an item to the array.